# TypesScript namespace - dynamic definition of fields (JS to TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, metaprogramming

I am trying to convert this JavaScript code from [atom/etch](https://github.com/aminya/etch/blob/9b90d6ad88b90b8a273992c540879b915d9967a2/lib/dom.js) to TypeScript without breaking the public API.

It defines both a `dom-function` and a `dom-array of functions` (both have the same name `dom`):

```js
// called by the following loop
function dom (tag, props, ...children) {
// ...
}

const HTML_TAGS = [
  'a', 'abbr'] // ... has more elements though
// similarly SVG-Tags is defined

// finds the array of functions
for (const tagName of HTML_TAGS) {
  dom[tagName] = (props, ...children) => {
    return dom(tagName, props, ...children)
  }
}

for (const tagName of SVG_TAGS) {
  dom[tagName] = (props, ...children) => {
    return dom(tagName, props, ...children)
  }
}

module.exports = dom
```

What is the equivalent TypeScript version of this?

Other packages use dom like `dom.a(tag, props, childern)`  [an example](https://github.com/atom/atom-select-list/blob/23d8d156765ee72fdfdd36bbe78485f33437c956/src/select-list-view.js#L246), or using `@jsx etch.dom` [an example](https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-ink/blob/4a1524d971cc4dd9dd99060909a4f7c9f6df3908/lib/util/etch.js#L2)

By running `dts-gen`, I get a namespace called `dom` which contains all the functions defined inside the for-loop.

```
export namespace dom {
    function a(props: any, children: any): any;
    function abbr(props: any, children: any): any;
//...
}
```

Here is [my branch](https://github.com/aminya/etch/tree/type_definitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're authoring a `dom.d.ts` type definition file for `dom.js`.

Namespace is not a proper type for `dom`. TS namespace in runtime JS is presented as plain object. But `dom` is both a callable function and an object with extra properties. Thus you should use an interface with callable signature to represent `dom` in TS.

**dom.d.ts**

```js
interface EtchElement<T extends string, P = any> {
  tag: T;
  props: P;
  children: any[];
  ambiguous: any[];
}

type EtchCreateElement<T extends string, P> = (props: P, ...children: any[]) => EtchElement<T, P>;

interface EtchDOM {
  <T extends string, P>(tag: T, props: P, ...children: any[]): EtchElement<T, P>;
  div: EtchCreateElement<"div", any>;
  // ... more tags here
}

declare const dom: EtchDOM;

export = dom;
```

---

### JSX Support

Now if you also intent to support JSX usage, you'll need to read through the official [JSX guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) first to learn the requirements. I'll highlight this excerption:

> Intrinsic elements are looked up on the special interface JSX.IntrinsicElements. [...] if this interface is present, then the name of the intrinsic element is looked up as a property on the JSX.IntrinsicElements interface.

Put together, here's a modest type definition that works:

```js
interface EtchElement<T extends string, P = any> {
  tag: T;
  props: P;
  children: any[];
  ambiguous: any[];
}

type EtchCreateElement<T extends string, P> = (props: P, ...children: any[]) => EtchElement<T, P>;

interface EtchDOM {
  <T extends string, P>(tag: T, props: P, ...children: any[]): EtchElement<T, P>;
  div: EtchCreateElement<"div", JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"]>;
  // ... more tags here
}

declare const dom: EtchDOM;

export = dom;

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Element extends EtchElement<any, any> {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      div: any; // constraint on props of "div" element
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Regarding your first assumption, I am trying to write the whole thing in TS: https://github.com/aminya/etch/tree/type_definitions/lib_src

Comment: @Amin you can merge my definition right into your `.ts` file. Copy paste, then change the export: `const _dom: EtchDOM = dom as EtchDOM; export default _dom;`